# Reload pagina y hacer scroll a div

Tags: javascript

tengo una pagina con un boton Actualizar, quiero que cuando se de a ese boton se recargue la pagina y me realice un scroll a un div pero cuando sea un F5 no haga el scroll. El problema que tengo es que no se distinguir cuando se hace un F5 y cuando se hace un windows.location.reload() (desde el boton)
pd// no puedo pasar valores por parametro GET

Alguna idea?

Comment: creo que es bastante sencillo, realizandolo dentro del evento `onclick` del boton, así solo lo realizará cuando lo pulses sin afectar a F5 o cargar de nuevo

Comment: necesito hacer la carga cuando se toque el  boton

Answer (score 1):

Apóyate con el método [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

Cuando se pulse el botón, añade a la URI una cadena de consulta con el ID del `<div>` (`ejemplo.html?id=foo`) y luego recarga la página con el método `location.reload()`.

Una vez recargada la página, revisa en la URI (`location.href`) si hay algún `?` presente (es el caracter que determina el inicio de la cadena de consulta). De ser así, obtienes el ID que se encuentra en la cadena de consulta y lo utilizar para tomar el `<div>`, y con ayuda del método `scrollIntoView()` realizas el *scrolling* hacia el elemento. Finalmente, eliminas la cadena de consulta de la URI, de tal manera que, si el usuario recarga la página con F5 o CTRL + R, no va a realizarse el *scrolling*.

Un ejemplo:

```
let button = document.querySelector("#buttonID");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    history.replaceState({}, document.title, location.href + "?id=foo");
    location.reload();
}, false);

let newUri = location.href;
if (newUri.indexOf("?") > -1){
    let divID = "#" + newUri.split("=")[1];
    document.querySelector(divID).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    
    let oldUri = newUri.substring(0, newUri.indexOf("?"));
    history.replaceState({}, document.title, oldUri);
}
```

Comment: Al final lo he hecho con un anclaje. Como te decía no puedo usar parametros